# The most elegant and efficient way of calculate union of a collection of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, union

I know I can use `Linq` to produce the union of 2 `IEnumerable` collections.

It should be something like:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> first;
IEnumerable<MyClass> second; 
IEnumerable<MyClass> union = first.Union(second);
```

Now suppose I have a collection of `IEnumerable` of my class, and I want to calculate the union of all of them. Any suggestion for an elegant (and possibly efficient) way of doing that?

I tried something like this, but that's not the right syntax:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>> collection;
IEnumerable<MyClass> result = Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>().Union( foreach (MyClass c in collection ){ yield return c;});
```

Comment: I allways think that the best answer is the most elegant and efficient one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach in O(n), as opposed to the method using `Aggregate` which is O(n²).

```
collection.SelectMany(i => i).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
collection.SelectMany(i => i).Distinct(); //will get your result.
```

Comment: He's not trying to flatten the sequence, he's trying to get the union of all of them... -1

Comment: @280Z28, I edited it shortly after posting, it was without distinct

Comment: I had the same solution. Hopefully it doesn't matter which duplicate is kept and which are removed.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I wanted to remove my downvote, but I noticed too late :/